# How do I resolve the dependencies when using Maven to build git plugin for Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to build and install the [git plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin) for Jenkins. Unfortunately, there aren't any instructions and I am new to Jenkins and Maven.

I have found [these](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-BuildingaPlugin) instructions but when I get to this step `mvn install` it fails on some dependencies. I've attempted many different ways to make Maven find the jars it's looking for, but without success. Here are the key output lines indicating the missing libraries:

```
Running InjectedTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.369 sec <<< FAILURE!
initializationError(InjectedTest)  Time elapsed: 0.017 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.jna.Native.open(Ljava/lang/String;)J

...

Running hudson.plugins.git.RevisionParameterActionTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 sec <<< FAILURE!
init ializationError(hudson.plugins.git.RevisionParameterActionTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase
```

I found the JNA jars [here](https://github.com/twall/jna) and downloaded them, but cannot get Maven to find them. How do I get Maven to find these jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had the openjdk installed. Once I installed the jdk from Oracle, and correctly ran `update-alternatives`, it ran the tests successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Are you building on a Linux system where the libjna is already installed ?

If so, try building with

```
mvn -DargLine="-Djna.nosys=true" install
```

Found [here](http://qa.ubuntu.com/2012/10/11/building-a-jenkins-plugin-on-ubuntu-quantal-12-10/).

Comment: qa@ScantronDevel:~/workspace/git-plugin$ sudo apt-get install libjna-java
...
libjna-java is already the newest version.

---

using the `-DargLine` you offered didn't result in a different outcome. Thanks though.

Comment: As described in the blog you linked, a `sudo apt-get remove libjna-java` fixed it for me.